# Amazon RDS - Create a Security Group NOT in Virginia?

Tags: security, database, rds, groups

It seems as though the management console only allows security groups to be created while in the "Virginia" selection. Is there a way to create a security group for an Oregon (or other)-based instance?

Comment: I can't login to the EC2 console right now, but you certainly can do that.  It's possible it's not available on Amazon's site (we use a third-party management system, and do it from there), but it seems unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely possible via the console. If you're in the EC2 section of the console, just select the "Virginia" dropdown in the header and switch to somewhere else.

This'll take you somewhere like this:
[https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=**us-west-2**](https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-west-2)